# Forking in loop results in weird behavior

Tags: c, fork

I have the following snippet of `C` code:

```
int i;
printf("ncams: %d\n", ncams);
for (i = 0; i < ncams; i++) {
    int *pips_fds = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    pid_t pid;
    pipe(pips_fds);
    printf("cproc_count in parent: %d, counter i: %d\n", cproc_count, i);// cproc_count is a variable declared above in code
    if ( (pid = fork())== -1) {
        logerr_r("cannot fork");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        if ( close(pips_fds[1]) < 0) {
            logerr_r("cannot close pipe");
        }
        printf("cproc_count in child: %d, counter i: %d\n", cproc_count, i);
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            free_cproc_id(cprocs[i]);//I don't need this in child process.
        }
        free(cprocs);// I don't need it also here in child process.
    } else {
        CProcID *cproc = malloc(sizeof(CProcID));
        cproc->id = ++cproc_count;
        cproc->pipes = pips_fds;
        if (close(pips_fds[0]) < 0) {
            logerr_r("cannot close pipe");
        }
        cprocs[i] = cproc;
    }

}
```

Now, the output from this is:

```
ncams: 2
cproc_count in parent: 0, counter i: 0
cproc_count in parent: 1, counter i: 1
cproc_count in child: 1, counter i: 1
cproc_count in child: 0, counter i: 0
cproc_count in parent: 0, counter i: 1
cproc_count in child: 0, counter i: 1
```

As you can see, I have `i = 1` for two times in parent. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What would you expect? Be aware the your threadcount will go exponentially. I suggest you to add process id output so you can distinguish which one was create by which process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you have `cproc_count in parent: 0, counter i: 1` being printed twice is because it is printed once by the parent, and then printed again by the child after the child has exited it's `else if` branch and looped around. You probably want to `break` out of the outer `for` within the child `else if` branch so that the child process doesn't also continue looping and forking new children.